# Unable to match two passwords in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing Registration form in Angularjs and i am new to the angularjs. I am doing validation. I have completed required field validation. I am doing now password and confirm password validation. Both password should match otherwise i am poping error message. I have refered https://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/angularjs-directive-to-check-that-passwords-match/.

```
 <div class="inputblock" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.password.$invalid && form.password.$dirty}">
                            <div>
                                <span class="ang-error" style="color:red" ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$invalid">
                                    <span ng-show="form.password.$invalid && form.password.$dirty">*</span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="ang-error" style="color:white" ng-show="form.password.$error.minlength">
                                    Too short!
                                </span>
                                <span class="ang-error" style="color:white" ng-show="form.password.$error.maxlength">
                                    Too long!
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="input-icon"><img src="images/lock-icon.png"></span>
                            <input type="password" class="with-icon" placeholder="{{ 'Password' | translate }}" ng-model="user.password" required="" name="password" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="15">

                        </div>


                        <div class="inputblock" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.confirmpassword.$invalid && form.confirmpassword.$dirty && form.confirmpassword.$error.pwmatch">
                            <span class="input-icon"><img src="images/lock-icon.png"></span>
                            <input pw-check='user.password' type="password" class="with-icon" placeholder="{{ 'Confirm Password' | translate }}" ng-model="user.confirmpassword" required="" name="confirmpassword">
                                <span  class="ang-error" style="color:red" ng-show="form.confirmpassword.$dirty && form.confirmpassword.$invalid && form.confirmpassword.$error'">
                                    <span ng-show="form.confirmpassword.$invalid && form.confirmpassword.$dirty">*</span>
                                    <span ng-show='form.confirmpassword.$error.pwmatch'>Passwords don't match.</span>
                                </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have controller code below.

```
(function (angular) {
    var app = angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('Registration', ['$scope', '$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', '$state', '$interval', 'toastr', 'cfg','$window',
 function ($scope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, $state, $interval, toastr, cfg,$window) {
//some code here
 }])
app.directive('pwCheck', [function () {

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
                elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        var v = elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val();
                        ctrl.$setValidity('pwmatch', v);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }]);

}(angular));
```

I have below error.

```
angular.js:12416 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 61-62 ['] in expression [form.confirmpassword.$dirty && form.confirmpassword.$invalid '].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2061-62%20%5B'%5D&p2=form.confirmpassword.NaNirty%20%26%26%20form.confirmpassword.%invalid%20'
```

May I get some help to fix this? I do not know what i am missing here. I am not able to figure out. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some modification in your html template

```
pw-check='SOME_ID_TO_COMPARE'
```

so in your first password you have to provide some id like "my_id_1" and then you have to pass that id in your second password's directive like pw-heck='my_id_1'.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. I am comparing it with model.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra apostrophe on line:

```
<span  class="ang-error" style="color:red" ng-show="form.confirmpassword.$dirty && form.confirmpassword.$invalid && form.confirmpassword.$error'">
```

at end:

```
.$error' <-- ">
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed that. Whenever i move cursor to confirm password my error message appears Passwords don't match. Even if i type correct password error message wont disappear. I do not have error now but password match is not working

Comment: Can you create plnkr?